Google API Calendar FreeBusy
I'm trying to request the freebusy endpoint in PHP using the googlecloud PHP sdk for a Resource Calendar (meeting room).
I created a project on the API console and a service account. I downloaded the credentials.json and requested the endpoint.
After many tries, the authentication seems to work but I get an error:
[errors] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Google\Service\Calendar\Error Object
                                (
                                    [domain] => global
                                    [reason] => notFound
                                )

                        )

I am absolutely sure about the CalendarID (checked it many times). So my service account doesn't have permission or scope to access it. Maybe because of "domain=global"? Or other?
The resource calendar has a meeting booked between the timeMin and timeMax I have set. If I use the Google API Sandbox directly, I can list the bookings.
Thanks
Axel

Your question isn't a minimal repro making it difficult to provide an answer. It is likely (!) that you're attempting to use a Service Account with a consumer (e.g. Gmail) calendar. This probably (!) won't work but may work if you share the calendar with the Service Account's email address (though this is a hack). You should use consumer user accounts directly to access user content when using Google's APIs. If you use Google Workspace, then you should create a domain-wide delegate and impersonate the user account.
